Kitchen sink back flow prevention
My kitchen sink sometimes gets flooded with lots of white foam from upstairs neighbors, and other times it gets flooded with nasty back flow water.  A couple of times plumber had to come clear the common main sewage line over 20ft away.  I'm on the first floor (3-story apt) and the last unit, so I'm tired of dealing with this. But most importantly I don't want to come to a flooded kitchen when I'm away.  What is the best device I can put under my sink between the p-trap and the wall to prevent back flow?  A check Valve? A backwater valve? A manual valve?
Thanks!


This is a problem for a professional plumber and not something to try to correct or "cover" with a band aide method.   If you have an upstairs neighbor you live in an apartment or condo.  This need to be brought to the attention of the property management and if a condo, the Board.  It involves sanitation conditions so it needs to be addressed ASAP.  Contact the management immediately, There are bigger issues going on here.

Believe me I have.  But I'm not going to let my kitchen flooded because of their incompetence and neglect.  Both times they sent a plumber, they tried to blame me and have me pay for the cost when clearly is not.

Notify them again and send the picture. It should have a time stamp to prove it is recent and not from before the last plumber visit.   if there is resistance get your local health department and department of housing involved.  The management will not ignore them.  I live in a condo. We have had to replace the management company, because one was totally incompetent regarding building repairs.  Not all companies are good but not all are bad either. Some need a kick in the pants to get things started.

What would you do if this was your apt, and the property management didn't do anything about it because it costs too much, and I'm the only one afected?   Serious question...

I agree, but I need a temporaty solution.  What is a harm in putting a backwater valve in there?

Putting a back flow may be against code. But if it isn't and one is installed, it could just cause the water to go to an alternative area, like the bathtub or sink.  Please remember I and any others on here are trying to give you the best advice we can.  What I would do is exactly what i am advising you to do.   If i got no results I would call my own plumber and get their opinion and If I had to,  pay for the repair myself. Then take my bill to the management company and demand reimbursement.

If the management company will not reimburse me, I go to court and file small claims.  However I do not have a case unless I can show that I have already taken all the steps I have told you to take.

That sewage line needs to be checked for blockages. Also that and the main stack need regularly scheduled cleaning which is the responsibility of the council / property management company.

your air-vent might no be working

A valve in your line will pressurize the sewer line and likely lead to a leak in the wall instead of in your sink.  Don't do it.  Get the property owner/association to fix it and/or move.  And make sure your renters insurance is up to date.

Make sure you have renters insurance too!
